# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method (Albumentations/NumPy)

Tags: numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library, data-augmentation, albumentations

Hi everyone can you please help me i'm getting this bug with random crop augmentation.
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

Code is below.

```
!conda install -c conda-forge gdcm -y

import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image
import cv2 as cv
import albumentations as A

import pydicom
from pydicom.pixel_data_handlers.util import apply_voi_lut

from tqdm.auto import tqdm

def read_img(path, voi_lut=True, fix_monochrome=True):
    dcm = pydicom.read_file(path)
    
    if voi_lut:
        img = apply_voi_lut(dcm.pixel_array, dcm)
    else:
        img = dcm.pixel_array
        
    if fix_monochrome and dcm.PhotometricInterpretation == "MONOCHROME1":
        img = np.amax(img) - img
        
    img = img - np.min(img)
    img = img / np.max(img)
    img = (img * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    
    return img

def resize_img(img, size, pad=True, resample=Image.LANCZOS):
    img = np.array(img)
    
    if pad:
        max_width = 4891
        max_height = 4891
        
        img = np.pad(img, ((0, max_height - img.shape[0]), (0, max_width - img.shape[1]), (0, 0)))
        
    img = img.resize((size, size), resample)
    
    return img

def augment_img(img, clahe=True, albumentations=True):
    if clahe:
        clahe = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=15.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
        img = clahe.apply(img)
    else:
        img = cv.equalizeHist(img)
        
    if albumentations:
        img = np.stack((img, ) * 3, axis=-1)
        
        transform = A.Compose([
            A.RandomSunFlare(p=0.2), 
            A.RandomFog(p=0.2), 
            A.RandomBrightness(p=0.2),
            A.RandomCrop(p=1.0, width=img.shape[0] / 2, height=img.shape[1] / 2), 
            A.Rotate(p=0.2, limit=90),
            A.RGBShift(p=0.2), 
            A.RandomSnow(p=0.2),
            A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.2), 
            A.VerticalFlip(p=0.2), 
            A.RandomContrast(p=0.2, limit=0.2),
            A.HueSaturationValue(p=0.2, hue_shift_limit=20, sat_shift_limit=30, val_shift_limit=50)
        ])
        
        img = transform(image=img)["image"]
        
    return img

img = read_img('../input/siim-covid19-detection/test/00188a671292/3eb5a506ccf3/3dcdfc352a06.dcm') #You can replace this with any .dcm filepath on your system
img = augment_img(img)
img = resize_img(img, 1024)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

This is for the SIIM Kaggle competition. I don't know how to solve this and the issue is with only random crop. I tried searching online but i was unable to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is in this line:

```
A.RandomCrop(p=1.0, width=img.shape[0] / 2, height=img.shape[1] / 2)
```

The problem here is that your width and height may not be integers, but they must be.

Check [Albumentations RandomCrop documentation](https://albumentations.ai/docs/api_reference/augmentations/crops/transforms/#albumentations.augmentations.crops.transforms.RandomCrop).

**And here is the solution.**

1. Explicitly convert width and height arguments to integer:

```
A.RandomCrop(p=1.0, width=int(img.shape[0] / 2), height=int(img.shape[1] / 2))
```

2. Use integer division:

```
A.RandomCrop(p=1.0, width=img.shape[0] // 2, height=img.shape[1] // 2)
```

Let me know if it helps!